# resample dataset with one irregular datetime

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe like the following. I wanted to check the values for each 15minutes. But I see that there is a time at 09:05:51. How can I resample the dataframe for 15minutes?

```
hour_min       value
06:30:00         0.0
06:45:00         0.0
07:00:00         0.0
07:15:00         0.0
07:30:00  102.754717
07:45:00  130.599057
08:00:00  154.117925
08:15:00  189.061321
08:30:00  214.924528
08:45:00  221.382075
09:00:00  190.839623
09:05:51       428.0
09:15:00  170.973995
09:30:00         0.0
09:45:00         0.0
10:00:00  174.448113
10:15:00  174.900943
10:30:00  182.976415
10:45:00  195.783019
11:00:00  200.337292
11:14:00        80.0
11:15:00  206.280952
11:30:00   218.87886
11:45:00  238.251781
12:00:00       115.5
12:15:00        85.5
12:30:00       130.0
12:45:00       141.0
13:00:00  267.353774
13:15:00  257.061321
13:21:00         8.0
13:27:19        80.0
13:30:00  258.761905
13:45:00  254.703088
13:53:52       278.0
14:00:00  254.790476
14:15:00  247.165094
14:30:00  250.061321
14:45:00  264.014151
15:00:00       132.0
15:15:00       108.0
15:30:00       158.5
15:45:00       457.0
16:00:00  273.745283
16:15:00  273.962264
16:30:00  279.089623
16:45:00  280.264151
17:00:00  296.061321
17:15:00  296.481132
17:30:00  282.957547
17:45:00  279.816038
```

I have tried this line, but i get a typeError.

```
res = s.resample('15T').sum()
```

I tried to make the index to date, but it does not work too.